# Loading external Dojo HTML fragment file using dojo.buttons

Tags: html, dojo, load, external

I'm trying to load an external HTML file (which is a dojo fragment) by click of a button.

So similar to:

index.html

```
<div dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" id="homepageView">
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id="reportNew">Report a New Incident</button>
</div>
```

view1.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
   <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='back:"Home">View 1</h1>
</div>
```

How can I load view1.html into homepageView view?

*I'm aware of the following approach:*

index.html

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
   <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='transition:"slide", url:"view1.html"'>
      External View #1 (sync)
   </li>
</ul>
```

view1.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
    <h1>view1.html</h1>
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem">
        Jack Coleman
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason `data-dojo-props='transition:"slide", url:"view1.html"'`  Doesn't work with button dojo types as far as I've tried.